# Window.Open causing issue when URL doesnot contain http

Tags: javascript, window

I have a textbox where the user can enter URL and button named Check link. On clicking button, a new window should be opened with the URL entered by the user. If i enter URL as  "http://google.com" then window.open('http://google.com'); is working fine but if i enter "www.google.com" then it is appending to the current window url (http://localhost:1234www.google.com) which is not a valid url. How to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check & prepend

```
if (!/^(http:|https:)/i.test(url))
   url = "http://" + url;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function f(url) {
    if (url.indexOf("http://") == -1) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    } 
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I solved in this way but by using regx to check http exists or not. It looks weird in this way. just trying for other ways. I am not understanding what causing the issue?

Comment: Good one from my point of view simply because we are not waisting resource on a regular expression when it's not needed. For the same result this has a low level of complexity if you compare to regex.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "How do I test if a string starts with 'http://' and if not prepend it?" then something like this:

```
var url = "somestring.com"; // as set from your textbox
if (0 != url.toLowerCase().indexOf("http"))
   url = "http://" + url;
```

It would be wise to trim leading and trailing spaces before doing this test, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

Add a onclick button function and handle the text in that.

```
function checkLink() {
    var url = document.getElementById("textbox-id").value;
   if(url.substr(0,7) != "http://") {
       alert("Invalid URL! Please make it like http://myurl.com");
    return false;
   }
}
```